# Autohokey how to compare copy text

Tags: autohotkey

I want to compare some text using `_Autohotkey_ likewise`

[image]

Save first copied text (B column) to `_var1_` and second copied text(C column) `_var2_`

But what I want is it need to write the missing text in column c or d

Comment: You've almost the same question for Excel. Why do you want to do it with autohotkey too?

Comment: Some of my mates said that is impossible in excel so i i thought maybe it is possible in ahk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in Excel or AutoHotkey... Excel might be easier since you would already have the text in columns and you could just use VBA.

You will need to use three loops...

One loop to iterate down the column, another loop to iterate on the comma delimited values, and a third loop to compare each delimited value to every value in the other column.

This process of 3 nested loops could be put into a function with the two input columns for arguments, afterwhich you could call it as func(colB, colC) for the first comparison and func(colC, colB) for the second comparison.

Comment: Ohh! Thank you for your response but i solved it with excel using vba with the help of Mate Juhasz and also i didn't get the iterate'ng thing(i'm newbie in AHK) anyway i posted another question if you help me in that i'll be grateful

Comment: Can u write a sample script how can I iterate the columns